# How to use in cypher escape character in file URL

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know that cyphers escape character is backtick, but when importing CSV from local file I do not how to use it properly. Basically this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///General Hospital Information.csv" as row 
return row limit 5
```

But this returns an error.

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 13:
>   file:/General Hospital Information.csv

I have tried putting backtick in the path to file string as a solution, but it does not work since it is in a string. Any idea how one can achieve this ? I mean besides renaming my file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these are urls, try using `%20` or `+` to replace the spaces:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///General%20Hospital%20Information.csv" as row 
RETURN row LIMIT 5
```

There is an [APOC function](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) to url encode strings:

```
WITH apoc.text.urlencode("General Hospital Information.csv") AS f
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///"+f as row 
return row limit 5
```

Comment: so neither does apoc.text.urlencode works because it replaces empty spaces with +